# Why os.remove() or shutil.move() can only move part of files

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I want to randomly choose 10 images from the training dataset to be the test data. If I only copy the selected data to the destination path, it works. But if I want to remove the source data, it can only remove some of them. I tried both os.remove() and shutil.move() function, but the issue remains. The below is my script:

```
for label in labels:

    training_data_path_ch1 = os.path.join(training_data_folder, label, 'ch1')
    test_data_path_ch1 = os.path.join(test_data_folder, label, 'ch1')
    training_data_path_ch5 = os.path.join(training_data_folder, label, 'ch5')
    test_data_path_ch5 = os.path.join(test_data_folder, label, 'ch5')

    ch1_imgs = listdir(training_data_path_ch1)

    # Randomly select 10 images
    ch1_mask = np.random.choice(len(ch1_imgs), 10)
    ch1_selected_imgs = [ch1_imgs[i] for i in ch1_mask]

    for selected_img in ch1_selected_imgs:
        ch1_img_path = os.path.join(training_data_path_ch1, selected_img)
        shutil.copy2(ch1_img_path, test_data_path_ch1)
        os.remove(ch1_img_path)

    print('Successfully move ' + label + ' ch1 images')
```

And I add an image to show the running status.

[image: Error Message]
You can see, the program indeed can copy the images and remove some of the images, but why it cannot remove all images?

Any ideas? I appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In:

```
ch1_mask = np.random.choice(len(ch1_imgs), 10)
```

You're potentially getting the same index returned more than once which means you're then trying to copy a file you've already copied and deleted (so you can't copy it again as it's removed), instead pass `replace=False`, eg:

```
ch1_mask = np.random.choice(len(ch1_imgs), 10, replace=False)
```